# Perl Text::CSV $csv->fields() property not populated

Tags: perl, csv

I've got a script that reformats incoming data from a CSV into a readable format by a vended system.  I may be going crazy, but I'm pretty sure it worked a week or two ago in the production environment.  However, at some point in the last week or two, it stopped working.  I tracked the problem down to the Text::CSV module not populating the $csv->fields() property.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => '|', allow_loose_quotes => 1});
$csv->column_names($csv->getline(*READ));
my @keys = $csv->fields;
```

Now, on my local machine (and, at least in my head, in the production environment two weeks ago, too), this would populate @keys with the parsed header fields.  However, now, in both production and pre-production, this fails.  The only difference I can tell is that my machine is running perl 5.12.4, while the prod/pprd is 5.8.8.  The Text::CSV module on both is 1.21.

On my machine, if I use Data::Dumper and dump the $csv object, part of the properties is

```
'_FIELDS' => [
    'ID',
    'IDCARD_TYPE',
    'FIRST_NAME',
    'MIDDLE_NAME',
    'LAST_NAME',
    ...
    'EMAIL',
],
```

On the other machines:

```
'_FIELDS' => undef,
```

I've worked around this by using $csv->column_names to populate @keys, but something doesn't seem right and I'd really like to figure out what's going on.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you dump `$csv->getline(*READ)` result?

Comment: It returns an array with the field names similar to what should be in the `_FIELDS` property and shows up in the `_COLUMN_NAMES` property.  This is identical on both my machine and the prod/pprd machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Text::CSV documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm#fields), returning `undef` is the expected result of `fields()` after calling `getline()`. Try using `parse()` first. You might be using a different version of this module on your local machine. You can check the version using `perl -MText::CSV -e 'print $Text::CSV::VERSION'`.

> Note that the return value is undefined after using getline (), which
>   does not fill the data structures returned by parse ().

Comment: is using `$csv->column_names` safe?  I've rewritten the code to use parse, and I can now use `$csv->fields`, I'm just trying to understand the proper way to use the module. `$csv->column_names`, according to the documentation, shouldn't be returning anything, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Following alternate sequence worked for me:

```
$file = "test.csv" ;      
if(!open($fh, "<", $file )) {
  # Cannot call getline is a symptom of a bad open() 
  printf("### Error %s: could not open file %s\n", $ws, $file) ;
  close($fh) ;
  exit 1 ;
}
while(my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  # $row is a pointer to an Array
  #     The array is already parsed.
  @items = @{$row} ;
  for(my $i=0 ; $i<=$#items; $i++) {
    printf("Field %d: (%s)\n", $i, $items[$i] ) ;
  }
}
close $fh ;
```